# How make invite window on Android Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Tell me how to implement this window, which opens by clicking on Share on Android? And what is the correct name for this window?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [share_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus) plugin supports all platforms. Published by the Flutter community.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I also found this package but did not understand how to connect what I need

Comment: First of all, you think about what you need to share then you pick this like an image, file, or something then you can share those thing over `flutter_share` or `share_plus` package

Comment: Tell me, can I change the color of the Share pop-up window? According to the standard, I have it white, but I need it to be dark

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Flutter_share](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_share) package. That would give you the same bottom window. You have looked at this.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try it and let you know if it helps)